# Jquery selector span with class

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I'm trying to use Jquery to select HTML elements with the following criteria

- Inputs that are enabled but not read only
- text areas
- selects
- spans with the class "file_label"
- not a button
- not hidden
- not a file

I have got them all to work so far apart from the span class with the following syntax:

```
$("input:enabled:not([readonly]), textarea, select, span[class='file_label']").not('.btn, .hidden, .file').each(function()
```

How do I get the span class check to work?

The span will be empty if there is no file uploaded:

```
<span class='file_label'></span>
```

Or if a file is uploaded:

```
<span class='file_label'>File_name.doc</span>
```

I want to count the empty spans with class file label.

I have a progress bar where I only want to check the values of certain field types. This is last hurdle that I'm struggling with! Help!

Comment: please post some html as well, maybe there is something wrong there?

Comment: Added what the html will look like in both scenarios... I hope that helps. Let me know if you need more

Comment: span class should be with double quotes. does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try span.file_lable instead of span[class='file_label']?

Answer (score 0):

Tom and you both, code should work. I thing, you are doing something wrong somewhere else.